# TemplateSyntaxError at 'bootstrap4' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of: bootstrap is installed and in INSTALED_APPS

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use `bootstrap_datepicker_plus` and to do that I need `bootstrap4`. I have installed it. when I run `pipenv run pip freeze`, I see:

```
django-bootstrap==0.2.4
django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus==3.0.5
django-bootstrap4==2.3.1
django-compressor==2.4
django-jquery==3.1.0
```

and I have in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
"bootstrap4",
"bootstrap_datepicker_plus",
```

But I still see

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /myapp/
'bootstrap4' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
```

when I include `{% load bootstrap4 %}` in my template.
Does anyone have an idea of why the tag is not registered? I have restarted the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django allows you to use different settings for different environments. My project was using this but left the settings.py file there which was not being used. There was a base.py file in the settings folder that I should have been editing.